# Simple Injector with RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider does not inject into custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter, simple-injector

I am converting current project from AutoFac to Simple Injector, but I can't make it work for my MVC action filter. My `UserProfileProc` attribute class contains a `UserProfile` of type `IUserProfile`, but it isn't injected into; its value is null.

My Action code like this

```
public class UserProfileProc : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
  IUserProfile UserProfile;
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
    UserLoginInfo userinfo = UserProfile.GetUserInfo(); .....
  } 
}
```

Update 1:
I change IUserProfile as public property, which said is null when run UserProfile.GetUserInfo();

```
public class UserProfileProc : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
  public IUserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
    UserLoginInfo userinfo = UserProfile.GetUserInfo(); .....
  } 
}
```

Update 2:
My current temp solution is:

```
public class UserProfileProc : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
  public IUserProfile UserProfile { 
      get { 
          return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserServer>(); 
          } 
    }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
    UserLoginInfo userinfo = UserProfile.GetUserInfo(); .....
  } 
}
```

My Injector Simple Injector Initializer class is

```
public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {            
        var container = new Container();
        InitializeContainer(container);

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider();

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
            new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {          
        container.Register<IAppClientServer, AppClientServer>();
        container.Register<IUserProfile, UserProfile \>();
        container.Register<ILogger, NLogLogger>();
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `UserProfile` as a property on `UserProfileProc`, and it is not public. Only public instance properties with a public setter are injected into attributes when you called `RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider`. All other things are just silently ignored.

For an alternative approach to using `RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider` with *implicit property injection*, please take a look at this [Stackoverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904103/simple-injector-filterinjection-seems-to-be-reinitialising-registerperwebrequest/17910073#17910073). For more information about property injection in Simple Injector, please read [this wiki](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Property-Injection).

Comment: I changed code like this: public IUserProfile UserProfile {get;set;}, now UserProfile is public property, but I get UserProfileis null when I tested.

Comment: @Ericyu67 And what happens when you request `IUserProfile` directly from the container? For instance: `container.GetInstance<IUserProfile>()`. Does this throw an exception?

Comment: Currently, my temp solution is like you said, it does work. But it seems bad code, I want to make injection work if it is possible.

Comment: @Ericyu67: What is your current temp solution? In my opinion, using implicit property injection (where properties can be skipped without failure) is bad, since it resulted in the situation you are in right now. IMO, the best solution is to split the meta data (the attribute) from its behavior as [described here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/472187#PostContent_1137461).

Comment: I changed my code base on your first comments set as public property, but id doesn't work. So I use my temp solution in Update2, It does work, but code like I said seems so bad.